# VBA - run code when macro interrupted

Tags: vba, excel

I have to change several defaults which my macro fixes at the end, but if I need to interrupt the macro, the settings will not be reset.
So if the code contains

```
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
```

then I would have

```
Private Sub IfInterrupted()
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
End Sub
```

Is there any way to do this?

Comment: How is the macro being interrupted?

Comment: If you are the cause of the interruption, you will just have to turn it back on yourself manually. There is no "Interrupt" Event to put code in.

Comment: Also consider *why* are you interrupting your code? Perhaps you can break it up into multiple parts so you don't need to, or add a way to handle that reason within the code?  This may be an [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Comment: Look at `Application.EnableCancelKey` https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/application-enablecancelkey-property-excel

Comment: @TimWilliams Just beat you:)

Comment: @braX Actually there is, sort of.

Comment: @robinCTS - nice... learn new things every day.

Comment: I'm interrupting (usually by mashing esc) because the code takes around 30m to run sometimes and as it's not finished, sometimes I need to interrupt it to make changes to the sheet or the code. I'm just looking for a way to make sure everything gets returned to normal automatically.

Answer (score 0):

If you really *really* need to do this, then this is how:

```
Sub YourSub()
  On Error GoTo ErrHandler:
  Application.EnableCancelKey = xlErrorHandler

  ' You code goes here

ErrHandler:
  With Err
    If .Number <> 18 Then
      .Raise .Number, .Source, .Description, .HelpFile, .HelpContext
    End If
  End With
  Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
End Sub
```

However, there are better ways to achieve whatever it is you are trying to achieve. For example, polling for user input.